# Why the variable created by `export` is empty?

Tags: linux, bash

I have the `env` file:

```
FOO=123
```

I need to read it and set its variables. I try to do it in my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
cat env | grep '^[^#]' | while IFS== read key value; do
    echo "echo: $key=$value"
    export "$key=$value"
done
echo "FOO -> $FOO"
```

The output:

```
echo: FOO=123
FOO ->
```

Why I get the `FOO ->` output instead of `FOO -> 123`?

Comment: Because you're piping input into the `while` loop, which runs it in a subshell. See e.g. https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/bash-cookbook/0596526784/ch19s08.html.

Comment: Well, I would start by reading the link I included in my earlier comment. There are lots of questions here on stack overflow that cover the same topic.

Comment: Also the BASH FAQ has an [entry on this subject](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).